# git -- how to see branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

this a silly question no doubt but I am a beginner and could not find the answer.. how can I launch a git branch somewhere on my site, without affecting my master branch.. so see the changes it contains?

I'm using RoR... thanks.

Comment: It's likely you need a staging instance of your site on which you can deplay a git branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a separate development/staging site to test your branch on, and if it works, then apply the changes to the live site. You can search around for how to set up a ROR staging site, and google will turn up plenty of examples (including results from Stack Overflow, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565647/best-practices-for-a-web-app-staging-server-on-a-budget) one.)

Answer (score -1):

I've written a guide for deploying a Rails site using Ubuntu which may be helpful to you:  http://ryanbigg.com/deployment/getting_started_ubuntu.html